# Use dplyr's _if() functions like mutate_if() with a negative predicate function

Tags: r, dplyr, data-transform

According to [the documentation of the `dplyr` package](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html#examples):

```
# The _if() variants apply a predicate function (a function that
# returns TRUE or FALSE) to determine the relevant subset of
# columns.
# mutate_if() is particularly useful for transforming variables from
# one type to another
iris %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)
```

So how do I use the inverse form? I would like to transform all non-numeric values to characters, so I thought of doing:

```
iris %>% mutate_if(!is.numeric, as.character)
#> Error in !is.numeric : invalid argument type
```

But that doesn't work. Or just select all variables that are not numeric:

```
iris %>% select_if(!is.numeric)
#> Error in !is.numeric : invalid argument type
```

Doesn't work either.

How do I use [negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) with `dplyr` functions like `mutate_if()`, `select_if()` and `arrange_if()`?

---

**EDIT: This might be solved in the upcoming dplyr 1.0.0: [`NEWS.md`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/92a3fbb275b897ee0250a1d58b9623b5b1dff833/NEWS.md#new-features).**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use shorthand notation `~` for anonymous function in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
     mutate_if(~ !is.numeric(.), as.character)
```

---

Or without anonymous function, use `negate` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
iris %>%
     mutate_if(negate(is.numeric), as.character)
```

In addition to `negate`, `Negate` from `base R` also works

```
iris %>%
   mutate_if(Negate(is.numeric), as.character)
```

Same notation, works with `select_if/arrange_if`

```
iris %>%
     select_if(negate(is.numeric))%>%
     head(2)
#  Species
#1  setosa
#2  setosa
```

Comment: Great options, many thanks! Still, `select_if(!is.numeric)` would be nice. I guess I'll go for `Negate()` for now.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a nice suggestion to add to their package, so feel free to open an issue on GitHub.

For now, you can write a function 'on-the-fly':

```
iris %>% mutate_if(function(x) !is.numeric(x), as.character)
iris %>% select_if(function(x) !is.numeric(x))
```

And this might even be safer, not sure how the `_if()` internals work:

```
iris %>% mutate_if(function(...) !is.numeric(...), as.character)
iris %>% select_if(function(...) !is.numeric(...))
```